# Is writing a number as two squares and writing the factors of a number equally hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np, decision-problem

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be the following:

$L_1=\{r:\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } x^2+y^2=r\}$

$L_2=\{(N,M): M<N,  \exists 1<d\leq M \text{ such that d|N} \}$

Claim $L_1 \leq_P L_2$

Sketch Proof

If I want to know whether $r\in L_1$.

The number of integer solutions to $x^2+y^2=r$ is given by

$g(r)=\sum_{d|r}{\chi{(d)}}$ where $\chi (x)=sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})=\cases{ 1\text{ when }x\cong 1 \text{ mod }4 \\ -1 \text{ when }x\cong 3 \text{ mod }4 \\ 0 \text{ when } 2|x }$

Then $L_1=\{r: g(r)\neq 0\}$. So then to answer is "$r\in L_1$?" is at most as hard to answer as "what are the divisors of $r$?"

$\square$

What I would like to know is if this is true the other way around. Is it true that if I had a machine which could tell me in constant time whether $r\in L_1$ could I create a machine which could answer "is $(M,N)\in L_2$?" in polynomial time?

**Motivations**

This question came out of a discussion on this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/is-satisfying-sum-i-1nx-iy-i-r-np-complete).

**Apologies**
I am really just a math.se member who has gotten lost and wandered on to cs.se. Let me know if my question is clear and up to the standards of this site. I am happy to make corrections.

Comment: Am I using $\leq_P$ correctly?

Comment: Your reduction $L_1\le_p L_2$ is correct, but your conclusion that $L_1$ is "as hard as" $L_2$ is incorrect. You just show that $L_1$ is *at most* as hard as $L_2$. Specifically, you actually show that $L_1$ is at most as hard as a very restricted case of $L_2$, which might be very easy.

Comment: Instead of "satisfying a circle", a better term could be "being a sum of two squares".

Comment: @Shaull, I changed some language to reflect your comment.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, Maybe the new title is closer to what I am asking.

Comment: Is it known whether computing the factors of $n$ and computing $\sum_{d|n}{d}$ are equally hard? Is that worthy of a separate post?

Comment: The title is phrased as if the question is a "functional" problem but the question is phrased as a "decision" problem. I think that shouldn't matter... as if we could demonstrate that the "decision" problems are equally hard than we would have also demonstrated that the functional problems are equally hard.  Right?

Comment: I suggest asking that in a separate post.  I hope you'll do some research first and show us your thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Computing $\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is in fact known to be as hard as factoring, up to a randomized polynomial time reduction. See Bach, Miller, and Shallit: [Sums of divisors, perfect numbers, and factoring](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/Papers/BMS86.pdf).

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423342/factoring-a-number-of-complex-integers. 

If you can write a number as two sums of squares then you can exploit this to find factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the situation as far as I can tell:

The most efficient way known to test membership in $L_1$ is to factor $r$.  No more efficient algorithm seems to be known.

However, there is no obvious reduction to prove $L_2 \le_P L_1$.  In other words, if we had a machine to decide $L_1$, there's no easy way to use that to factorize.  If we want to factor a number $N$, we can check whether $N \in L_1$, but this only gives us one bit of information about the factors of $N$.  Testing multiples of $N$ (i.e., whether $cN \in L_1$ for some integer $c$) doesn't give us any additional information, as knowing whether $N \in L_1$ suffices to predict whether $cN \in L_1$ for all $c>0$.  Testing other numbers doesn't seem to help in any obvious way, either. (Testing whether $N' \in L_1$ for some other number $N'$ doesn't seem to give any useful information, if $\gcd(N,N') =1$; and if we had a way to find another number $N'$ such that $\gcd(N,N')\ne 1$, we'd already know how to factor, but of course we don't know how to do that -- so any number we know how to generate is unlikely to give us any useful information on the factors of $N$.)  This is not a proof; it is just handwavy intuition.

So it seems plausible that $L_1$ might be easier than $L_2$, and it also seems plausible that they might be of the same difficulty.  I'm not aware of any further results on this subject.